# Instantiating a java if statement referencing an error

Tags: java, error-handling, boolean

How would one write an "if statement" that checks if an error occurred in a method if so it would start a separate method  that deals with the error otherwise open the next method

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean, but usually you'd use exceptions for this...

Comment: It depends how the first method reports an error.

Comment: What kind of error? Perhaps you could use Try-Catch? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called [Exception Handling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html).

Example:

```
void someMethod()
{
    try
    {
        // Open a File
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        // Call another method
    }
    finally
    {
        // this block executes whether exception occurs or not
    }

    // Continue execution
}
```

Comment: Exception handling it is then

Answer (score 0):

Use a try catch statement for this. Assumign you want to crash out if the first method errors (after dealing with the exception) then the below format should work

```
try {

    methoda();

} catch(Exception e) {

    methodToDealWithError(e);
    throw(e);
}

methodb();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think `try-catch` block will do it for you. call your first method in `try` block, then call your method which deals with exceptions in `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Exceptions? Make the method throw an exception on error, catch the exception in the calling code, place error handling in the catch block??? That's what Exceptions are for!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the method reports the error. If it returns "false" upon error you can do a trivial test:

```
boolean res = method();
if (!rest) {
  // manage error
}
```

If the method however raises exception, you have to catch them with:

```
try {
  method();
} catch (Exception e) {
  // Manage exception or raise
}
```

Actually it depends on how method is implemented. Can you give some more info ?

Answer (score 0):

**methodA**: The first method, it throws an exception in case en error occurs
**methodB**: next Method to execute, if no error occurs
**methodC**: error dealing method

```
try{
    methodA();
    methodB();
catch(Exception e){
    methodC();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Exception handling by using try catch block as

```
try {
    Place Your Code Here...
} catch(Exception e) {

   callAnotherMethodHere();
}
```